# JQuery. Как узнать точное значение margin, если стоит auto

Tags: jquery

**Дано**: есть *div* элемент c *css* свойством '*margin: auto*'.

При исполнении кода на странице сайта:

```
elem = $('_нужный_элемент_');
elem.css('margin-left');
```

выдает значение *auto*;

Если, мы этот же самый код исполним в консоли браузера то получаем конкретную цифру. Как получить точный *margin-left* в цифрах у данного элемента?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/geek_of_cola/xz526wpk/2/ :DDD

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  var marginLeft = parseFloat($('#block').css('margin-left'));
  console.log(marginLeft);
});
```

```css
#block {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='block'>
  TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: С чем может быть связанно, что данный код **var marginLeft = parseFloat($('#block').css('margin-left')); console.log(marginLeft);** выдает у меня auto?

Comment: @KanzafarovS. какая у вас версия jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Ничего подобного. Проверил на конкретном примере в консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стили:

```
.link-btn {
   margin: 0 auto 14px;
}
```

Проверял в Хроме. Оказывается, поведение еще и от браузера зависит. Сниппет ниже выдает:

в Хроме и Opera

```
0px 261px
261px
0px 261px
261px
```

В IE11, Edge и Mozilla

```
(пусто)
261px
(пусто)
261px
```

```js
$(function() {
  var margin = $('#block').css('margin');
  var marginLeft = $('#block').css('margin-left');
  var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('block'));
  console.log(margin);
  console.log(marginLeft);
  console.log(computedStyle["margin"]);
  console.log(computedStyle["margin-left"]);
});
```

```css
#block {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='block'>
  TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению у меня так. Очевидно есть причина, почему скрипт отрабатывает так. Возможно, вы сталкивались ранее с подобным поведение скрипта?

Comment: Добавьте пример кода в вопрос. Покажите, что на вашем коде именно так.

Comment: Какой браузер у вас? Дополнил ответ.